# Помогите с кодом Python 3

Tags: python

Вводится запись корректно но при попытке вывести на экран из файла выдает **ошибку:**

```
b = g[1]
```

IndexError: list index out of range

**КОД:**

```
        if k[4] != 'не установлено приложений\n':
            d = k[4].split(' - ')
            for e in d:
                if e != '':
                    g = e.split()
                    i = g[0]
                    b = g[1]
                    self.добавить_приложение(i, b)
```

Comment: если Ваш вопрос решен, не нужно его удалять. Просто поплюсуйте тех, кто по мог и поставьте галочку лучшему (это  уже похоже сделали)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В строке 
`self.список_приложений = self.список_приложений + ' - ' + c.имя_пользователя + ''+str(c.название_pc)`
происходит запись в файл, после чего мы имеем:

`username;PCname;2017-11-20 15:20:04.277522;None; - app_nameapp_key`

Как видите `c.имя_пользователя + '' +str(c.название_pc)` записываются слитно,
а здесь вы хотите их разделить `g = e.split()`, но получаете `['app_nameapp_key']`

Вам нужен новый разделитель между "**app_name**" и "**app_key**", например "|".

И несколько замечаний:

- старайтесь приводить пример кода на латинице
- указывайте версию питона
- Старайтесь давать одинаковых названий внутри класса

Comment: Спасибо, я уже решил этот вопрос. Самое забавное, что у меня был разделитеть в виде пробела в кавычках(но он не перенесся при копировании из блокнота) Возможно проблема с кодировкой. Так же благодарю за остальные замечания, учту ) Просто в питоне недавно.

Answer (score 0):

не, предположим, ругается потому, что тут

```
for e in d:
```

вы ходите уже по словам. А тут

```
g = e.split()
```

пытаетесь разбивать слова, в результате чего g[1] действительно нет

а вот почему так происходит - это вопрос уже Вам себе задавать нужно

Comment: я хотел разбить строку на слова, можете сказать, что именно тут реализовано неправильно? При запросе g[0] у меня выводятся оба слова без разбиения

Comment: показать входную строку можете? сложно из кода понять ее содержимое. Точнее даже входной файл